# Botium with DialogFlow unable to keep context in memory

Tags: testing, dialogflow-es, chatbot

We are developing a DialogFlow agent and we have a backend with firebase cloud functions that verify the data send by the user and send a event to the agent to ask the user the next question or the same again if go wrong.

If we test with iOS/Android or from DialogFlow chat the parameters of the context go to the function filled, but when we use Botium livechat go empty and the function respond with the angent to say the same question again.

We have a context 7a that nee to keep in memory all the conversation, we defined in without parameters `botium.json`.

This context 7a is pretty complex with a lot of parameters, it's like json structure, and names varying between test.

**How we can keep that context with all its data in memory of botium?**

**This is a OK example:**

> me
>
> New shipment
>
> bot
>
> ¿From who you want to send the shipment?
>
> me
>
> From Mike
>
> bot
>
> ¿How is the address?

.... more

**This is a KO example:**

> me
>
> New shipment
>
> bot
>
> ¿From who you want to send the shipment?
>
> me
>
> From Mike
>
> bot
>
> ¿From who you want to send the shipment?

Thanks for the help

Comment: The botium dialogflow connector is enable for holding the context. If it doesn't work out for you, then this is maybe a bug. Can you provide verbose output from a test run please.

Comment: @FlorianTreml sorry, but i dont know what do you mean with "verbose output from a test run", we use Botium Box.

We test with other fresh agent more simple and simple webhook, and minimal login in firebase, and with only 2 intent and go well.

It contains only intent A that mean the name and then a intent B that save the direction of the name. 
And the conversation is like the above. 
In the last test we use it without custom botium.json, only required capabilities to connect.

Now, we are changing logic of the agent and the firebase funtions, and see how far we go until begin errors.

Comment: can you give me developer access (ftreml at gmail.com) to a minimal dialogflow agent showing this problem with your context

Comment: Hi, we added you to the agent BorBot like developer, regards

Comment: Copied the agent and tested. I cannot really spot a problem, maybe because I am not speaking spanish. can you please provide me a convo sample file which should work on the agent.

Comment: @FlorianTreml I send you a mail with a convo conversation sample  and explanation of wrong behavior. Thanks again

Comment: hm, didn't receive anything up to now (ftreml "at" gmail.com)

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the mail direction, send again